# I am following spring xml based configuraiton so How TokenBasedRememberMeServices configuration in spring-security.xml file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

i already implemented following class in my security package

public class TokenBasedRememberMeServices extends AbstractRememberMeServices

but when i tried to configure remember-me bean in

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"> <!-- enable remember me --> <remember-me token-validity-seconds="1209600" remember-me-parameter="remember-me" data-source-ref="dataSource" /> </http>
```

---

it will not worked so is there any other configuration i have to add in my spring-security.xml file ???

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your xml file :

```
<beans:bean id="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider"
                class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices">
        <beans:property name="key" value="_spring_security_remember_me"/>
        <property name="alwaysRemember" value="true"/>
        <beans:property name="tokenRepository" ref="jdbcTokenRepository"/>
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
    </beans:bean>

// Do you see below createTableOnStartUp, just keep it true for one time, //run the webapp, stop it, make it false and re-run it.

    <beans:bean id="jdbcTokenRepository"
                class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl">
        <beans:property name="createTableOnStartup" value="false"/>
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </beans:bean>
```

If you have doubts, lemme know.